# Missing 16:10 resolutions with Nvidia drivers (Can't add resolutions)

Tags: drivers, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a laptop with a Nvidia 9650M GT and used the drivers that Seven brought me. It works fine but Metro 2033 tells me that I have to upgrade my drivers to play the game. So I did it.

But since I did a clean install of the new Nvidia drivers, I just have 1440*900 or 4:3 resolutions.

I usually played with 1280*800 or 1184*740 (for performance issue)
With the "old" drivers I was able to create custom resolution (1184*740) in Nvidia control panel but now when I try it tells me that "my monitor cannot support this resolution".

When I insist, it works but soon as I shut down my computer I have to recreate it..

Do anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [this tool](http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) for forcing custom resolutions to become permanent.
Take some care as it seems to be very advanced, don't mess with anything you don't know.

[Found on this topic](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1732773) on Hardforum.com

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CarlB Sorry! Fixed.